# Не работает обработчик

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, есть код

```
$('.id_produkt').click(function(){

    id_product=parseInt($(this).val());

    proverka=zakaz[id_product];

    if(proverka=='0') {

        zakaz[id_product]=1;
        name_produkt=$('#name'+id_product).val();

        $('#left_column').append('<br>'+name_produkt+'<span class="kolichestvo" id="quant'+id_product+'" style="display: inline; margin-left: 10px;">1</span><br>');

    } else {
        zakaz[id_product]++;

    }

});

$('.kolichestvo').click(function(){
          id=$(this).prop('id');
          alert(id);
       });
```

Вот второй обработчик не желает работать, в чем может  быть причина? с первым все хорошо

Comment: `<экстрасенс>`У вас переменная `id` где-нибудь объявлена?`</экстрасенс>`

Смотрите в консоль, наверняка там будет сообщение об ошибке. Ещё было бы неплохо выложить код страницы и скрипт на http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: переменная объявлена, проблема была найдена, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не с jquery проблема, а с чтением документации. rtfm http://api.jquery.com/on/

Потому что вы повесили обработчик на все элементы с классом "kolichestvo", которых на момент установки обработчика ровно 0 штук. Надо примерно так:

```
$(document).on('click','.kolichestvo',function(){
  var id=$(this).prop('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

ЗЫ вместо `$(document)` можно написать `$('#left_column')`...

Comment: спасибо, все работает